# How to remove Key Without using Foreach laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

```
$bloklistArray = BlockList::select('phone_number')->get();
```

Output

> ```
>  [{"phone_number":"1234567890"},{"phone_number":"1234567891"},{"phone_number":"1234567930"}]
> ```

Expected Output

> ['1234567890','1234567891']

I have lot of Datas in Block list so How to get The Values without key And without using foreach

Comment: Why not `1234567930` ?

Comment: "_Expected Output_" You don't want `1234567930` in there?

Comment: `array_column($bloklistArray, 'phone_number')`

Comment: Using  `pluck()`

Comment: array_values();

Comment: `$bloklistArray = BlockList::select('phone_number')->get()->pluck('phone_number');`

Comment: typical, laravel has a function for it ;p

Answer (score 7):

Use [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_pluck) instead of `select` and `get`.

```
$bloklistArray = BlockList::pluck('phone_number');
```

This will get the values of a single column as an array directly from the database.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That is the `pluck` function on a collection. The pluck function I referenced is on the Laravel query builder and calls the select query directly. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L2146

Comment: @Ragupathi glad I could help, consider marking this as the answer to your question so other users might also find this.